# Invoke a receiver on set the live wallpaper in android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, live-wallpaper

Kindly tell me how can I listen to live wallpaper change in android ?
what i have tried: 
I have made a receiver in android which listens to wallpaper change action.

```
<receiver
            android:name=".Wallpaper_Change"
            android:enabled="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.WALLPAPER_CHANGED"/>
             </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

It is invoking only on setting a static image as wallpaper but it is not invoking on setting live wallpaper.

Comment: No, I did not get any solution. :(